# supersized jquery links colors not changing on slides heres my code.. Thankss in Advance

Tags: jquery

[Its my html file where i added classes to the link of the header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClRVG.png) [And Here's my code for the logic to change the color of main bar links when the background changes but it doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEt2f.png)

Comment: Please include your actual code in the question, not pictures of it. However it looks like you haven't included jQuery.js in the page and your code relies on it

Comment: Its like they are giving too many errors while i m writing code here so i put screen shot here , how to include it

Comment: Just copy and paste - but please take the time to format it so it's readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what what help in changing the color is the before animation method , i have to call the link changing code in it and it works perfectly fine now